# ANSI logging with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-logback

I use Logback logging with Spring Boot 1.5.15.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-color-coded-output) I should be able to disable the ANSI logging (colour output) using the configuration `spring.output.ansi.enabled=never`.

This appears to work fine in the local console however not in a Docker environment. Has anyone running into this ?

Answer (score 4):

`spring.output.ansi.enabled=never` is the answer to the problem even at the Docker level. However, in my situation this was set in the base image with the environment variable `SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS` and so for some reason the `application.yaml` configuration was being ignored.

Precedency is documented further in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config